# ReactJS - put overflown elements into a “…” dropdown button when screen is shrink

Tags: reactjs

[image]

there is 10 development div in a row and i want to display 7 and remaining show in dropdown button when we use lx-px and when shirink it toward the mobile resolution its automatically decreases to 6, 5, ... and remaining added to dropdown button.

Comment: you have to give us some code samples of your tryings. also look at this thread how to properly ask a question: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect first what is the dimension of your parent element, then, if each of your elements have a fixed size, it's trivial to determine how many of them will fit into it.

If your elements don't have a fixed size, then you need to check the size of each of them and compute how many of them will fit.

What remains to do is displaying the elements that fit into your screen and display the rest in your dropdown

A few leads:

[window.resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize)

[element.getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

[React refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)